# Scaffolding new Ruby on Rails app leads to spring error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had tried to run a Rails app locally after finding that a deployed version of it had stopped running, but I got the error below. Puzzled, I tried to scaffold a new Rails app and got the same error. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4).
We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system.
To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs.
This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `block in load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/home/user/code/rails-who/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you following the warning message instructions?

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4).
We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system.
To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.
```

I would try the two things suggested in the warning messages:

### 1.) Run the command `gem install bundler:2.1.4`

### 2.) Regenerate your binstubs `bundle exec spring binstub --all`

Comment: yes. I tried that but I didn't include that since it was issued as a warning and not an error. Also doing that doesn't make that warning go away for some strange reason.